# Adding sbt native packager plugin in SBT

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a very organized build file that is composed of the following scala files:

1. Build.scala - the main Build file
2. Dependencies.scala - where I define the dependencies and the versions
3. BuildSettings.scala - where I define the build settings
4. plugins.sbt

A snippet of the Build.scala is as below:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  import Dependencies._
  import BuildSettings._
  import NativePackagerHelper._

  // Configure prompt to show current project
  override lazy val settings = super.settings :+ {
    shellPrompt := { s => Project.extract(s).currentProject.id + " > " }
  }

  // Define our project, with basic project information and library dependencies
  lazy val project = Project("my-project", file("."))
    .settings(buildSettings: _*)
    .settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        Libraries.scalaAsync
        // Add your additional libraries here (comma-separated)...
      )
    ).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
}
```

All the 4 files that I mentioned above are in the same directory which is inside the project directory. But when I run this build file, I get the following error:

```
not found value: NativePackagerHelper
```

Any clues why his this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to use the following in my build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.11
```

I originally had 0.13.6 and it was causing the import statements to fail!

Comment: I recommend using a build.sbt. Build.scala is deprecated and will be removed in SBT 1.0.